# Multiple LEFT JOINS for the same column

Tags: sql, left-join

I am in SQL and am attempting to fill out a single column using multiple Left Joins. My first LEFT JOIN is below:

```
 SELECT a.*, b.Game_Code
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[MasterSheet] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Date, Visit_Team_Code, Home_Team_Code
  from dbo.game2018) b
  ON (a.Date = b.Date and a.[Team Code] = b.Visit_Team_Code and a.[Opponent Code] = b.Home_Team_Code)
```

All of this comes through great. It creates a new column called Game_Code and fills out 1/6 of the column with the rest of the column being NULL. For the rest of the nulls I am needing to do this same Left Join except where the Team codes are switched. This new Left Join on its own would like like the following:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Game_Code
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[MasterSheet] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Date, Visit_Team_Code, Home_Team_Code
  from dbo.game2018) b
  ON (a.Date = b.Date and a.[Team Code] = b.Home_Team_Code and a.[Opponent Code] = b.Visit_Team_Code)
```

I only want to do this join on the remaining NULL values though. When I try to run both left joins together I get errors. The reason I'm needing to do this is because each game is listed twice. Once with the visit team code and then home team code and then again with the home team code first and visit team code second. I know this probably is confusing, but I don't want to create multiple Game_Code columns I only need 1.Please see an example below: The two tables are on the left and the desired result on the right.
[First Left Join would satisfy the second row of the desired result and Second Left Join would satisfy the first row, but I can't figure out how to put them together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLKt3.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Try removing the `team_code` criteria from the join and using in a `case expression`

Comment: Sample Data and Desired Results have been added

Comment: Next time, please don't use images, but post your data as text. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And please tag your DBMS when asking SQL questions. I suppose it is SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're `LEFT` joining the same table twice, could you just join on it once and add an `OR` to your join and use both conditions?

```
SELECT a.*, b.Game_Code
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[MasterSheet] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Date, Visit_Team_Code, Home_Team_Code
  from dbo.game2018) b
  ON a.Date = b.Date and 
((a.[Team Code] = b.Visit_Team_Code and a.[Opponent Code] = b.Home_Team_Code)
OR
(a.[Team Code] = b.Home_Team_Code and a.[Opponent Code] = b.Visit_Team_Code))
```

Comment: You're awesome WAMLeslie. That was the exact solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want an `INNER JOIN` and there is no need for `DISTINCT`:

```
select ms.date, ms.team_code, ms.opponent_code, g.game_code
from dbo.mastersheet ms
join dbo.game2018 g on g.date = ms.date 
                   and g.home_team_code in (ms.team_code, ms.opponent_code)
                   and g.visit_team_code in (ms.team_code, ms.opponent_code)
order by ms.date, ms.team_code, ms.opponent_code;
```